# How to find parent element by class name using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How can I properly access the parent element of a tag using BeautifulSoup? I've the following structure:

```
<div class="TableContainer">
  <div class="CaptionContainer">
    <div class="CaptionInnerContainer">
      <!-- There is N other span elements here -->

      <span class="CaptionVerticalLeft"></span>
      <div class="Text">Character Information</div> <!-- Content that I am filtering -->
      <span class="CaptionVerticalRight"></span>

      <!-- There is N other span elements here -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <table class="Table3" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="InnerTableContainer">
            <table style="width: 100%">
                <!-- Content that I want -->
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

There are `N` structures on the website like this and in order the get the right information I'm filtering first by the text "Character Information", then I want to get the first parent with class `TableContainer` so after this, I'll be able to find the `table` with the content that I want.

The current code returns `None` when I try to `find_parent`

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

char_title = soup.find("div", string="Character Information")
# result is: <div class="Text">Character Information</div>

parent = char_title.find_parent("div", {"class": "TableContainer"})
# result is: None

parent = char_title.find_parent("div", _class="TableContainer")
# result is: None
```

How can I find the parent with a specific class?

Comment: you first find the element `el = soup.find(...)` then you use `el.parent.parent.parent`

Comment: I also tried the `find_parent` methods you used and they worked, and its `class_` not `_class`

Comment: Is the website public?

Comment: Works for me too, no problem (and again, its `class_` if you want to use that syntax)

Comment: @QHarr yes, here is it: `https://www.tibia.com/community/?name=Rubini`

Comment: @AlbertoHanna @chirown88 I've tried also with `class_="TableContainer` and still returns `None`

Comment: @AlbertoHanna If I try to use `.parent` the return is the full HTML of the website

Comment: For that website URL can you show what your expected output would be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First locate the containing div for each block. Then search for the title to decide if it is the block you want. If it is, use the same search to locate the required table inside the block. For example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from unicodedata import normalize

url = "https://www.tibia.com/community/?name=Rubini"
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")

for div in soup.find_all('div', class_="TableContainer"):
    title = div.find('div', class_="Text").text

    if title == "Character Information":
        table_inner = div.find('table', class_="Table3").table
        
        for tr in table_inner.find_all('tr'):
            row = [normalize('NFKD', td.get_text(strip=True)) for td in tr.find_all('td')]
            print(row)
```

Giving you output:

```
['Name:RubiniTitle:Exalted (21 titles unlocked)Sex:maleVocation:Elder DruidLevel:1305Achievement Points:411World:LibertabraResidence:ThaisGuild Membership:Leader of theLibertabra PuneLast Login:May 18 2022, 22:17:16 CESTComment:"Frase motivacional de Lideres antigos de Guerras"First Level 1000 on RetroHardcore Servers.Rubini formerly Shanera and Calvera@Since 2007836a95f1d69460734766489384f641cbAccount Status:Free Account', 'Name:', 'Rubini', 'Title:', 'Exalted (21 titles unlocked)', 'Sex:', 'male', 'Vocation:', 'Elder Druid', 'Level:', '1305', 'Achievement Points:', '411', 'World:', 'Libertabra', 'Residence:', 'Thais', 'Guild Membership:', 'Leader of theLibertabra Pune', 'Last Login:', 'May 18 2022, 22:17:16 CEST', 'Comment:', '"Frase motivacional de Lideres antigos de Guerras"First Level 1000 on RetroHardcore Servers.Rubini formerly Shanera and Calvera@Since 2007836a95f1d69460734766489384f641cb', 'Account Status:', 'Free Account']
['Name:', 'Rubini']
['Title:', 'Exalted (21 titles unlocked)']
['Sex:', 'male']
['Vocation:', 'Elder Druid']
['Level:', '1305']
['Achievement Points:', '411']
['World:', 'Libertabra']
['Residence:', 'Thais']
['Guild Membership:', 'Leader of theLibertabra Pune']
['Last Login:', 'May 18 2022, 22:17:16 CEST']
['Comment:', '"Frase motivacional de Lideres antigos de Guerras"First Level 1000 on RetroHardcore Servers.Rubini formerly Shanera and Calvera@Since 2007836a95f1d69460734766489384f641cb']
['Account Status:', 'Free Account']
```

The text is normalized using `unicodedata.normalize()`

Comment: I manage to get the first table information but the page has "N" tables and I need to extract the information based on the table's title, this is why I need to first, get the "table title" and then try to find the table content.

Comment: First find the div that contains both, if it has the correct title then find the inner table below. I have updated the answer